# Linux media streaming server?

Tags: linux, video-streaming

we need to implement a media/video streaming solution on Linux, a-la youTube but for our internal use. Any decent open source tools for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a streaming server, you can use [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's lots. Have a google for [progressive download video php](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=progressive+download+video+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a). There's a free player and code samples [here](http://www.rich-media-project.com/progressive-download-products/flv-player/index.html).

You'll also need something like [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for manipulating the video files

Comment: If you're going to deliver progressive download, just use the base HTTP Server.  The only time you should consider an application server is if you needed some sort of access control and even then there's better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 has some nice streaming features, check it out.